# DNS - Multiple Root TXT Records

Tags: dns

My email provider has requested that I add the following DNS entries:

```
@ 600 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.myemailproivder.com mx ~all"
@ 600 IN TXT "verification=128763812763817638163"
```

However, my DNS host, Gandi, doesn't allow multiple TXT records with the same name.

Can anyone suggest an alternative way of maintaining both of the above DNS records?

I've tried using:

```
mydomain.com 600 IN TXT ...
```

but this doesn't work (presumably resolving to `mydomain.com.mydomain.com`)

I also tried:

```
mydomain.com. 600 IN TXT ...
```

but Gandi won't allow the dot after the name.

Comment: ...Gandi doesn't allow that? That's really surprising. Have you tried contacting their tech support to see if this might be just a bug in their DNS management UI?

Comment: I was surprised too. I wasn't sure if it was a general DNS restriction? I contacted their tech support, who replied "Unfortunately you cannot have two records with the same name "@" and the same type "TXT" on your domain zone file."

Comment: Put it on the same line then, "verification" right after "all".

Comment: It's definitely not a DNS restriction. You can have as many records of the same type as you want (except SOA and CNAME).

Comment: Putting everything on the same line, as per Frank Sixteen's suggestion, seems to allow SPF verification — albeit with an invalid syntax error caused by the additional verification string.

Comment: Gandi is broken if they don't allow this. Consider moving your DNS somewhere else.

Comment: So it is definitely valid to have two (or more) DNS TXT records named '@'?

Comment: @TheRogueWolf: It's even valid at gandi. See CMCDragonkai's comment on S. Pokorny's answer. You just have to give them the same TTL :-/

Comment: In Azure DNS, restriction is the same: `New-AzureRmDnsRecordSet : The Record set @ exists already and hence cannot be created again.` Same TTL doesn't work. Is it valid to add multiple String into one TXT "@" record?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. I went to expert mode and added the TXT line manually:

```
@ 300 IN TXT "verification=128763812763817638163"
@ 300 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.myemailproivder.com mx ~all"
```

this should do it. Once back in normal mode both TXT entries show up

Comment: If the TTLs are the same, this trick works. If the TTLs are different then Gandi complains even on the expert panel.

Answer (score 2):

Adding:

```
@ 600 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:spf.myemailproivder.com mx ~all verification=128763812763817638163"
```

(as per Frank Sixteen's comment) seems to allow the record to be detected and passed by online SPF verifiers — albeit with some reporting invalid syntax for the additional verification string.

Comment: But whatever is looking for the verification will probably fail